# A question about the conjunction "while"

Tags: conjunctions, ellipsis, clauses, parts-of-speech

> Isaac Newton changed the world while in quarantine from the plague.

> Isaac Newton changed the world while he was in quarantine from the plague.

*while* is clearly a conjunction in the second sentence because it connects two independent clauses.

Is *while* a conjunction in the first sentence as well? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, because 'he was' is understood.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Thanks. So it's just a case of ellipsis?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.